# Find Div after specific element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, element

I am able to grab all the HTML inside the element with the .class textimage-text.  This works fine.  I then need to grab the html inside the following Div, which does not have an id or a Class..

Example

```
<div class="textimage-text">
  <p>Some Text goes here</p>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <p>Some additional Text goes here</p>
</div>

$.get(item.url, function (html) {

  var body = $(html).find(".textimage-text").html(); // <- this works
  var more= $(html).find(".textimage-text").next("div").html(); // <- this does not work
```

Comment: I don't think any of them will work because `html` is response coming from `$.get`. so cn you tell what's the value of `html` ?

Comment: the var body line definitely works.

Comment: what is the value of `html` ? can you let me know? do `console.log(html);` inside `$.get` and let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use General sibling selectors `~` (ex: `~ div` find next div that is a sibling to this)

```
$(html).find(".textimage-text ~ div").html();
```

or

```
$('.textimage-text ~ div').html()
```

> ### General sibling selectors
>
> The general sibling combinator (~) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it follows the first element (though not necessarily immediately), and both are children of the same parent element.

Example:

```js
console.log($('body').find('.textimage-text').html());
console.log($('body').find('.textimage-text ~ div').html());

console.log($('.textimage-text').html());
console.log($('.textimage-text ~ div').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textimage-text">
  <p>Some Text goes here</p>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <p>Some additional Text goes here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra **.next()** and remove the **"div"** argument in the next function, currently you're selecting the **br**

```
var more= $(html).find(".textimage-text").next().next().html()
```